# PySpark Error: StructType can not accept object 0 in type <type 'int'>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My data file is related to Graph Edges. Every line has the format of (src node & dest node). This id my Schema definition.
`eschema = StructType([StructField("src", StringType(), True), StructField("dst", StringType(), True)])` 
I've tried to read the line, split it by the delimitter (',') and convert each element into an int. But this fails somehow.

```
 lines = sc.textFile(filename)
 lines = lines.map(lambda l : map(int, l.split(delim)))
 lines = lines.map(lambda l : Row(l[0], l[1]))
```

On running this, I'm getting the error 
`StructType can not accept object 0 in type <type 'int'>`
I'm using Python 2.7, Spark > 2.0. After splitting the line, the objects are of type Unicode and not string, would that make any difference. How to resolve this. Any suggestion would be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter is ',' than it's just a regular csv file.
Since you are on Spark > 2.0 you can user modern data frames api; instead of using spark context (by convention sc) you can use spark session:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\ # if you have a header inside the file, otherwise don't put this line
    .option("schema", eschema)\ 
    .load(filename)
```

Instead of providing schema through `.option("schema", )` you can also use `.option("inferSchema", "true")` which will try to guess the file structure by looking at data.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the Answer. But the problem is some of the files are CSV, other files have " " as the delimiter. Also, my local system has Spark > 2.0. The remote cluster I'm using has Spark 1.6 which I can't upgrade.  These are the errors.                                          On remote cloud (Python 2.7, Spark 1.6, Graphframes 0.1.0):
Unexpected tuple 0 with StructType
On My PC (Python 2.7, Spark 2.4, Graphframes 0.7.0):

StructType can not accept object 0 in type <type 'int'>